# Does there exist a non-field Noetherian domain whose field of fraction is the field of real numbers?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

> Does there exist a Noetherian domain (but not a field) whose field of fractions is the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Since you ask for a noetherian example, you might want to include a non-noetherian example, you are aware of.

Comment: If yes then $\mathbb R$ is the field of fractions of a noetherian local domain, hence of a DVR. This shows that the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^\times$ has a quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. Is this possible?

Comment: why the domain will be local ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497256/when-is-a-field-a-nontrivial-field-of-fractions?rq=1 A non-noetherian example is given here.

Comment: oh ..i understand, localizing at any non-zero prime ideal will give that Noetherian local domain whose field of fraction will be the same as that of the first domain.

Comment: @user26857 why should the local Noetherian domain be a DVR? Or How do you obtain a DVR from a general Noetherian local domain?

Comment: @PavelČoupek See [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PH). One can also use the Mori-Nagata Theorem: the integral closure of a noetherian domain is a Krull domain, and then localize at a height one prime.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks.

Comment: @Panja : if such a Noetherian domain , which is not a field , exists then it must have positive dimension , then passing to a height one prime ideal we have a Noetherian domain of dimension 1 and then taking its integral closure , since the field of fractions remains the same , and the integral closure is still Noetherian (by say Krull-Akizuki theorem) we may assume our Noetherian domain is normal also . Now let $a$ be a positive real number which irreducible in our normal Noetherian domain , then $(a)\subset (\sqrt a) \subset (\sqrt {\sqrt a} ) \subset ...$ gives a non-ending ascending chain