# Is an infinite field always isomorphic to a non-trivial fraction field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, integral-domain

Out of the blue, I asked myself the following question:

> Is an **infinite** field always isomorphic to the fraction field of an integral domain which is itself not a field?

Please note that the above setup avoid answering by *a field is its own fraction field*.

I think this question is natural as it is kind of a converse to the following:

> **Proposition.** The rings which can be embedded into some field are exactly the integral domains.

As fraction fields have no characteristic properties that I am aware of, I am lost on how to tackle this problem. Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1.** My question only involves infinite field as a finite integral domain is itself a field and the result failed to be true in this case. - pointed out by [carmichael561](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/314708/carmichael561) in the comments below.

**Edit 2.** The result holds for field of [characteristic zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497256/when-is-a-field-a-nontrivial-field-of-fractions?rq=1). - link provided by [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur). As for now, the interesting question is the following:

> Is an **infinite** field of **prime** characteristic isomorphic to a non-trivial fraction field?

Comment: Since a finite integral domain is a field, the answer would seem to be no for finite fields.

Comment: @carmichael561 Indeed, this is a neat observation! I am editing.

Comment: What integral domain would you suggest to obtain $\Bbb R$? (I'm not saying there is none, but I don't think there is a natural or even constructive one)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Actually, $\mathbb{R}$ is the genesis of my thoughts. I failed to see it as a non-trivial fraction field and also failed to prove there is none.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497256/when-is-a-field-a-nontrivial-field-of-fractions?rq=1) (it was the top of related questions) answers it for characteristic $0$, it seems. A transcendence basis as used in the answer does require the axiom of choice.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}$ (which also made me wonder about this question), such a subring would be dense (wrt to the usual topology)

Comment: Very interesting question +1

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for the link, it was not suggested to me when I asked the question. I am editing to keep track of the progress.

Comment: @C.Falcon I think the related questions when writing a question and when a question is posted are different. Or at the very least, you will have to check again once you've finished writing the question but before you post it (which I find to be a very laborious way of searching).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47103/is-every-field-the-field-of-fractions-of-an-integral-domain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A field $K$ is the fraction field of a proper subring iff $K$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some $p$.  First, if $K$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then every subring of $K$ is a field (since the subring generated by any single element is finite and a finite domain is a field), so $K$ cannot be the fraction field of a proper subring.

Conversely, if $K$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for any $p$, let $B$ be a transcendence basis for $K$ over the prime field and let $R$ be the subring of $K$ generated by $B$.  Note that $R$ is not a field: if $K$ has characteristic $0$, this is because $R$ is a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$, and if $K$ has characteristic $p$, this is because $R$ is a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{F}_p$ in at least one variable since $B$ is nonempty by hypothesis.  Let $S$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $K$.  Since $K$ is algebraic over $R$, $K$ is the field of fractions of $S$.  Since $S$ is integral over $R$ and $R$ is not a field, $S$ is not a field either.

Comment: I am grateful you gave me a detailed answer, I was able to follow it. Thank you!