Of which Integral Domain's Quotient field extension is the field of real numbers R?
I am being exposed to rings and fields for the first time. As i learnt that any integral domain can be extended to a field by taking quotients, can there exist an integral domain $D$ for any field $F$ such that $F$ is the quotient field extension of $D$ and $D$ is a proper subset of $F$?
For the field of real numbers $R$, can such an integral domain $D$ exist for which $R$ is its quotient field extension and $D$ is a proper subset of $R$? I had been thinking about it. No subset that only has rationals will be able to take on transcendental numbers thus $D$ must have transcendental numbers such that quotienting them will generate all the transcendental and algebraic numbers. How could one construct such a $D$?
Furthermore if it is impossible, then is there any condition/reason on $R$ that explains why such an impossibility exists?

A more general question was answered here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497256/when-is-a-field-a-nontrivial-field-of-fractions

As mentioned by eti902 in the comments, this answer by Alex Youcis shows how, in the case of characteristic zero, every field is the quotient field of a proper integral domain which is not a field.
Here is the situation is positive characteristic $p > 0$ (although I believe you do not know so much about positive characteristic if you just started with fields). First of all, for any finite field $\Bbb F_{p^m}$, the answer is no: there is no proper integral domain $R$ such that $\Bbb F_p = \operatorname{Frac}(R)$. Indeed, such $R$ would be a finite integral domain, hence a field (take a nonzero element $x \in R$, consider the multiplication by $x$, it is injective, hence surjective, so $x$ admits an inverse), hence it is its own quotient field, and so $R = \Bbb F_{p^m}$.
This allows us to extend the result to subfields $F$ of the algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$. If $R$ is again a subring of $F$, take $x \in R$, $x$ belongs to a finite field $\Bbb F_{p^m}$, so $R \cap \Bbb F_{p^m}$ is a finite subring, hence a field, so $x$ has an inverse in $R$: $R$ is again a field.
Finally, consider a field $L$ of transcendental degree at least 1 over the finite field $\Bbb F_p$: then the answer is yes. We can repeat Youcis' argument, namely, consider $(X_i)$ a transcendence basis of $L$ over $\Bbb F_p$, take $R$ to be the integral closure of $\Bbb F_p[(X_i)]$ in $L$. Then (if I am not mistaken) $\operatorname{Frac}(R) = L$, yet $R$ is not a field.
